# Is it possible to create a cross-project security group

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

As titled, I want to create a security group that can be used in all projects.

Let's said I have two security group:

1. server-sg
2. corey-sg

A server running in admin project, its security group (server-sg) restrictions only allow the access source that has a specific security group (corey-sg), like this:

```
server_sg:
  type: OS::Neutron::SecurityGroup
  properties:
    name: server-sg
    rules:
      - protocol: tcp
        direction: ingress
        port_range_min: 3389
        port_range_max: 3389
        remote_group_id: { get_resource: corey-sg }
        remote_mode: remote_group_id
```

But, if I create corey-sg in admin project, I can't use it in any other projects, how do I create a security group that can be shared/recognized/used by all projects' instances, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `RBAC(Role-Based Access Control) policy`, check from "[Sharing a security group with specific projects](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/admin/config-rbac.html#sharing-a-security-group-with-specific-projects)".

FYI.

> No other users (other than admins and the owner) will be able to see the security group.

Comment: Seems the type `security_group` is only supported after Stein. Anyways, thanks for your idea.

Comment: Sorry, it's supported since Train, here is the [Docs](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/train/cli/command-objects/network-rbac.html).

Comment: Welcome, I also learn from your good question.